# Flutter Dart: Future.wait() pass value by reference?

Tags: dart, flutter

In a scenario like the following, how to pass a variable `List<Document> itemList` by reference ?

```
Future.wait([futDocs]).then((dataRet){
  dataRet.forEach((doco) {
    var docList = doco.documents;
    docList.forEach((doc){
      var docTitle = doc['title'];
      print("data is $docTitle");
      itemList.add(docTitle); <--- change not reflected outside this function
```

The `itemList` does not change when `itemList.add(docTitle)` is performed in the above Future.wait(). I believe the reason is because `itemList` is not passed by reference. If I cannot pass `itemList` by reference, how can I make this work? Can I return `dataRet` as a list and use it outside `Future.wait()`?

*Adding more info...*

Above call is performed within the constructor of `class ListBuilder` as shown in the following code:

```
class ListBuilder {
 List<Document> itemList = new List<Document>();

 ListBuilder(){
   var futDocs = Firestore.instance.collection('Data').orderBy('time').limit(10).getDocuments();

   Future.wait([futDocs]).then((dataRet) {
     dataRet.forEach((doco) {
       var docList = doco.documents;
       docList.forEach((doc){
         var docTitle = doc['title'];
         print("data is $docTitle");
         itemList.add(docTitle); <--- change not reflected outside this function

  [...]
```

While waiting for an answer, i have tried custom setters and getters as well as the use of `this.itemList.add(...)` but without success.

Any help, it is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you define -  itemList - Can You Paste More Code .?

Comment: Hi anmoi, I added some more context and code

Answer (score 0):

More code would be helpful, but the first things that come to mind are these:

1. It will probably work to call `await` before your `Future.wait` so that the asynchronous code is for sure run
2. This seems less likely, but you may have to call `setState` when adding your to your list

Edit:

I would suggest code like this:

```
class ListBuilder { 
  List<Document> itemList = new List<Document>();        

  Future<void> myFunc(var futDocs) async {
    await Future.wait([futDocs]).then((dataRet){  
    [...] *Rest of your Future code here*
  }

  ListBuilder() {
   var futDocs = Firestore.instance.collection('Data').orderBy('time').limit(10).getDocuments(); 

   myFunc(futDocs)

  [...]
```

Comment: Hi Conner, I added some more context. Please let me know what you think

Comment: BTW, I have looked into `setState`. I am getting `[dart] The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'ListBuilder'. [undefined_method]` error. However, I used the same syntax for the Future.wait. What is another way of implementing Future.wait in the above context? Another note, `print("data is $docTitle");` it gets executed. There no execution problem it's just values assigned inside this function are limited within the function and don't persist after

Comment: I updated the suggestion, but what are you using this for? Like is it just a dart object passing data to a widget?

Answer (score 0):

All objects in Dart are passed by reference.
The problem is likely [itemList] isn't updated immediately because Future.wait is an async function. Any code dealing with itemList has to run inside the callback function ( `.then((dataret) { ... });` ).

```
class ListBuilder {
    List<Document> itemList = new List<Document>();

    ListBuilder() {
    var Docs = 
    Firestore.instance.collection('Data').orderBy('time').limit(10).getDocuments();

    Future.wait([futDocs]).then((dataRet) {
        dataRet.forEach((doco) {
            var docList = doco.documents;
            docList.forEach((doc) {
                var docTitle = doc['title'];
                itemList.add(docTitle);
            });      
        });
        /* 
           itemList has been updated here because we are inside a callback function that 
           runs _after_ Future.wait has completed.
        */
    });
    /*
       itemList hasn't been updated here _yet_ because this code runs immediately, 
       regardless how long the Future.wait call takes to complete.           
    */
    }    
}
```

If you want you can use async/await logic instead of a callback function, which is often easier to read and maintain. More info here: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your response. How do I convert `Future.wait([futDocs]).then((dataRet)` into a `Future<void> what_here_?() async {` ? The `Future.wait([futDocs]).then((dataRet)` return a list of `DocumentSnapshot`, how do I achieve the same result from `Firestore.instance.collection('Data').orderBy...`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem however it was not related to pass value by reference. Thank you for your answers, they actually got me thinking and pointed me in the right direction. 
The following was the solution to a problem which is not the one raised above :D LOL

**Tl;dr; answer:**

Change the widget to use `streamBuilder`

**Long answer**

The problem was due to the fact that changes to a list were not reflected outside the `.then()` function. Well, the issue itself is not related to how the list was passed to the function but to the use of async/await logic. When the app is executed, it will populate the `itemList` in `Widget` with the current items in the list - this is empty when it starts. In the meanwhile, with an async call, firebase fetch the data and list is updated. However, the UI is not changed. Now, `setState` gave me an idea but was not the solution. In my case, I don't need a stateful Widget but rather the use of `StreamBuilder` within the creation of the widget. This bind the list to the async call with the use of `stream`

```
new StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('data').orderBy('time').limit(10).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return itemList...
```

Thanks again!